# Using Q_Property to display properties

Tags: c++, qt, qobject, qproperty

I have a GUI displaying a tree architecture as shown here.

[image]

Each of those nodes are separate classes that are derived from the node above them. All of them inherit `QObject` for their implementation.
Now I need to add a few properties to be displayed when the user selects `Properties` under the Right-Click menu of `Implicit`. Selecting this opens a window with the properties.
I added these properties in the header file of `Implicit` like so :

```
#ifndef FCIMPLICIT_H
#define FCIMPLICIT_H
#include <QObject>
#include "Interface.h"
#include "ResourceItem.h"
#include "MonWindow.h"
#include "FCTab.h"
#include "ResourceItem.h"
#include "FCAbstract.h"
#include "FCInterface.h"
#include "FCConnections.h"
class CFCImplicit: public CResourceItem
{

    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int FCPortID READ getPortID )
    Q_PROPERTY(QString Type READ getType )
    Q_PROPERTY(QString Status READ getStat )    
    Q_PROPERTY(int WWNodeNumber READ getNodeNo )
    Q_PROPERTY(int WWPortNumber READ getPortNo )
    Q_PROPERTY(bool AutoActive READ getAuto )
public:
    CFCImplicit(QObject*);
    ~CFCImplicit();

    QString                 getType();
    QString                 getStat();
    int                     getPortID();
    int                     getPortNo();
    int                     getNodeNo();
    bool                    getAuto();


};
```

`FCinterface.h` is the header of the `FCASM` node.

**The issue is that only the first property is displayed, as seen in the second picture. Is there a reason why this is happening? Am I supposed to add something to the constructor or a new function?**

The constructor for the `Implicit` class is

```
CFCImplicit::CFCImplicit(QObject* parent) : CResourceItem(parent)
{

    fnSetProperty("objectName", QString("Implicit"));   
    ((CResourceItem*)parent)->fnAddResources(this);

}
```

EDIT:

This is the code for all the `READ` functions

```
QString CFCImplicit::getType()
{
QString a;
a="Implicit";
return a;
}

QString CFCImplicit::getStat()
{QString a;
a="Idle";
return a;}

int CFCImplicit::getPortID()
{int a;
a=1;
return a;}

int CFCImplicit::getPortNo()
{int a;
a=2;
return a;}

int CFCImplicit::getNodeNo()
{int a;
a=2;
return a;}

bool CFCImplicit::getAuto()
{bool a;
a=true;
return a;}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you extract the properties of the selected object to add them in the property table?

Comment: @BenjaminT I have added the code but they don't do anything. I defined them just so that I could demonstrate the addition of properties. The functions just return predefined values.

Comment: I did not mean the code of the getters. I meant the code where you retrieve the list of properties of the object. It should contains calls to `QMetaObject::propertyCount()` annd `QMetaObject::property(int)`.

Comment: I haven't added any code for that. What purpose do those lines serve? I am going to (wrongly, perhaps) assume that they only return an `int` with the number of properties, if so how do they affect the properties being displayed?

Comment: Yes you did add code for that. Either by writing it directly or by using a library. To understand why the properties are not displayed in the property table, you need to find how the property table works. Si if you do not give any detail about the property table, no one will be able to help you. (on a side note, do not assume what a function does, but read the doc!)

Comment: Could you explain what you meant by details about the property table? I am building these additional features on top on a lot of existing code. I thought that the property window was an object that belonged to `QObject`. Should I be looking for a custom class that describes this property table? (And I am going through the `QMetObject` doc as we speak! )

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I was doing wrong. I assumed that since the properties were read only, I only needed a `READ` accessor function. By adding the `WRITE` accessor and adding the required `WRITE` functions, the properties were displayed. I don't exactly understand why this condition is required (maybe having just `READ` just makes the properties available for introspection), but it worked! So there you go.

Happy coding everyone!

Answer (score 0):

No need to add the READ and the function, you can use the MEMBER to have direct access to the variable.

Comment: I'm using [Qt 4.7.0](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/properties.html) , MEMBER wasn't added until later versions. I'm terribly sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: can't you update Qt? I mean, 4.7 is unmaintained for a *long* time.

Comment: I realised that when I had to look for documentation in the Qt archives! But it is a company project, and they developed it in 4.7. Will it work just the same in later versions of Qt? Are later versions just additions to the older versions or have they changed how different things work?

Comment: A few things should change but if you are using Qt Widgets there are not many changes - A lot of projects still compiles with Qt4 *and* Qt5 together, same codebase.